# How to finish Sharepoint Online Remote Login with obtained Security Token using PHP Curl

Tags: php, sharepoint, sharepoint-rest-api

I am attempting to authenticate to a Sharepoint Online instance with an obtained security token for an account.  I have found various places discussing this but get hung up when actually trying to pass the token to sharepoint to login.

Here is my code to obtain the security token (which is working)

```
    $xml = '<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"
      xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"
      xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
  <s:Header>
    <a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1">http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/trust/RST/Issue</a:Action>
    <a:ReplyTo>
      <a:Address>http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous</a:Address>
    </a:ReplyTo>
    <a:To s:mustUnderstand="1">https://login.microsoftonline.com/extSTS.srf</a:To>
    <o:Security s:mustUnderstand="1"
       xmlns:o="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
      <o:UsernameToken>
        <o:Username>MYUSERNAME</o:Username>
        <o:Password>MYPASSWORD</o:Password>
      </o:UsernameToken>
    </o:Security>
  </s:Header>
  <s:Body>
    <t:RequestSecurityToken xmlns:t="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/trust">
      <wsp:AppliesTo xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy">
        <a:EndpointReference>
          <a:Address>https://MYSHAREPOINTINSTANCE.sharepoint.com/</a:Address>
        </a:EndpointReference>
      </wsp:AppliesTo>
      <t:KeyType>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/NoProofKey</t:KeyType>
      <t:RequestType>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/trust/Issue</t:RequestType>
      <t:TokenType>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.0:assertion</t:TokenType>
    </t:RequestSecurityToken>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>';

$curl = curl_init("https://login.microsoftonline.com/extSTS.srf");
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, ["Content-Type: text/xml"]);

        $result = curl_exec($curl);
```

The result of this is giving me the token response as I expect

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<S:Envelope xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"
            xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd"
            xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd"
            xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy"
            xmlns:wst="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/trust" xmlns:S="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
    <S:Header>
        <wsa:Action S:mustUnderstand="1" wsu:Id="Action">http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/trust/RSTR/Issue
        </wsa:Action>
        <wsa:To S:mustUnderstand="1" wsu:Id="To">http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/role/anonymous
        </wsa:To>
        <wsse:Security S:mustUnderstand="1">
            <wsu:Timestamp wsu:Id="TS"
                           xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
                <wsu:Created>2018-10-10T13:44:01.2979816Z</wsu:Created>
                <wsu:Expires>2018-10-10T13:49:01.2979816Z</wsu:Expires>
            </wsu:Timestamp>
        </wsse:Security>
    </S:Header>
    <S:Body xmlns:S="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
        <wst:RequestSecurityTokenResponse
                xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd"
                xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy"
                xmlns:wst="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/trust">
            <wst:TokenType>urn:passport:compact</wst:TokenType>
            <wsp:AppliesTo>
                <wsa:EndpointReference xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
                    <wsa:Address>https://MYSHAREPOINTINSTANCE.sharepoint.com/</wsa:Address>
                </wsa:EndpointReference>
            </wsp:AppliesTo>
            <wst:Lifetime>
                <wsu:Created>2018-10-10T13:44:01Z</wsu:Created>
                <wsu:Expires>2018-10-11T13:44:01Z</wsu:Expires>
            </wst:Lifetime>
            <wst:RequestedSecurityToken>
                <wsse:BinarySecurityToken Id="Compact0"
                                          xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
                    RETURNEDTOKEN
                </wsse:BinarySecurityToken>
            </wst:RequestedSecurityToken>
            <wst:RequestedAttachedReference>
                <wsse:SecurityTokenReference
                        xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
                    <wsse:Reference URI="wmKM3OmbJLqPMfRK77SN0Isxyoc="></wsse:Reference>
                </wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
            </wst:RequestedAttachedReference>
            <wst:RequestedUnattachedReference>
                <wsse:SecurityTokenReference
                        xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
                    <wsse:Reference URI="wmKM3OmbJLqPMfRK77SN0Isxyoc="></wsse:Reference>
                </wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
            </wst:RequestedUnattachedReference>
        </wst:RequestSecurityTokenResponse>
    </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

Now I post that security token to login to Sharepoint

```
$curl = curl_init("https://MYSHAREPOINTINSTANCE.sharepoint.com/_forms/default.aspx?wa=wsignin1.0");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "RETURNEDTOKEN");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, ["Content-Type: text/plain"]);
$result = curl_exec($curl);
```

I get a 302 response however

```
<html><head><title>Object moved</title></head><body>\r\n
<h2>Object moved to <a href="https://login.microsoftonline.com/login.srf?wa=wsignin1%2E0&amp;rpsnv=4&amp;ct=1539179869&amp;rver=6%2E7%2E6631%2E0&amp;wp=MBI&amp;wreply=https%3A%2F%2FMYSHAREPOINTINSTANCE%2Esharepoint%2Ecom%2F%5Fforms%2Fdefault%2Easpx%3Fapr%3D1&amp;lc=1033&amp;id=500046&amp;guests=1&amp;wsucxt=1&amp;cobrandid=11bd8083%2D87e0%2D41b5%2Dbb78%2D0bc43c8a8e8a">here</a>.</h2>\r\n ◀
</body></html>
```

If I include curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); in the request, or try to POST to the redirect URL directly, I am just returned HTML for a login screen and it's not actually doing anything with the security token in the post data that I'm sending.